# Action Icons appearing as plain text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I am using material-table (https://material-table.com/#/) for a react project and I have imported the icons that I need to use, but inside the action bar the actions are appearing as plain text, and not as the Material Icon.

```
import React, { forwardRef } from 'react';
import MaterialTable from 'material-table';

import AddBox from '@material-ui/icons/AddBox';
import ArrowUpward from '@material-ui/icons/ArrowUpward';
import Check from '@material-ui/icons/Check';
import ChevronLeft from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronLeft';
import ChevronRight from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight';
import Clear from '@material-ui/icons/Clear';
import DeleteOutline from '@material-ui/icons/DeleteOutline';
import Edit from '@material-ui/icons/Edit';
import FilterList from '@material-ui/icons/FilterList';
import FirstPage from '@material-ui/icons/FirstPage';
import LastPage from '@material-ui/icons/LastPage';
import Print from '@material-ui/icons/Print';
import Remove from '@material-ui/icons/Remove';
import SaveAlt from '@material-ui/icons/SaveAlt';
import Search from '@material-ui/icons/Search';
import ViewColumn from '@material-ui/icons/ViewColumn';

const Table = ({columnData, data}) =>{
   const tableIcons = {
        Add: forwardRef((props, ref) => <AddBox {...props} ref={ref} />),
        Check: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Check {...props} ref={ref} />),
        Clear: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Clear {...props} ref={ref} />),
        Delete: forwardRef((props, ref) => <DeleteOutline {...props} ref={ref} />),
        DetailPanel: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ChevronRight {...props} ref={ref} />),
        Edit: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Edit {...props} ref={ref} />),
        Export: forwardRef((props, ref) => <SaveAlt {...props} ref={ref} />),
        Filter: forwardRef((props, ref) => <FilterList {...props} ref={ref} />),
        FirstPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <FirstPage {...props} ref={ref} />),
        LastPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <LastPage {...props} ref={ref} />),
        NextPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ChevronRight {...props} ref={ref} />),
        PreviousPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ChevronLeft {...props} ref={ref} />),
        Print: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Print {...props} ref={ref} />),
        ResetSearch: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Clear {...props} ref={ref} />),
        Search: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Search {...props} ref={ref} />),
        SortArrow: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ArrowUpward {...props} ref={ref} />),
        ThirdStateCheck: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Remove {...props} ref={ref} />),
        ViewColumn: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ViewColumn {...props} ref={ref} />)
    };


    return (
        <MaterialTable
            columns={columnData}
            data={data}
            options={{
                search: false,
                toolbar: false,
                showTitle: false,
                sorting: false
            }}
            actions={[
                {
                    icon: 'Print',
                    tooltip: 'Print Label',
                    onClick: (event, rowData) => alert("You printed " + rowData.description)
                }
            ]}
            icons={tableIcons}
        />
    )
}

export default Table;
```

I would expect for the actual Print Icon to appear but it appears as text reading 'print'. Also occurs if I use lower case 'print'. If I use  the table throws an error.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had that problem as well and updated the typescript docs accordinly. You have to wrap them in a function. And to enable the tooltip, you have to forward the ref since muiv4 like this:

```
Add: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Add {...props} ref={ref} color='action' />)
```

Comment: I am doing that in the tableIcons const. And the other icons are appearing, it just seems to be in the Actions Column that it doesn't work

Comment: Oh i see, you have to write it lower case: icon: 'print'

Comment: Tried that as well, same outcome. It just changes the text to a lowercase 'p'

Comment: Seems like a bug, I will try to PR a fix.

Comment: Ok so i looked into the implementation and if you want to use a custom element, you have to pass it as a element and not the string refernece. So if you jsut remove the '' from your icon, it will pass the material-ui icon from the import as prop, which will be render correctly:   icon: Print, where Print is import Print from '@material-ui/icons/Print';

Comment: Like this? ```actions={[
                {
                    icon: print,
                    tooltip: 'Print Label',
                    onClick: (event, rowData) => alert("You printed " + rowData.description)
                }
            ]}```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197167/discussion-between-domino987-and-eesteban).

Comment: Solve: actions={[
                {
                    icon: Print,
                    tooltip: 'Print Label',
                    onClick: (event, rowData) => alert("You printed " + rowData.description)
                }
            ]}

Answer (score 22):

I just used the same library and it is either an error in the documentation or code bug, anyway it is fixed as follows:

```js
actions={[
  {
    icon: () => <AddBox />,
    tooltip: 'Add User',
    onClick: (event) => alert("You want to add a new row")
  }
]}
```

Obviously you must change the action and the icon to what you want to use.

Comment: This worked!!! I didn't to pass it as a function `actions={[{icon: <AddBox />}]}`, but the element itself... and it fixed the issue! Thank you Alejandro

Answer (score 5):

I tried the following which solved the problem for me
1)Icon imported from material-ui/icons

```
import ExitToAppIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExitToApp';
const tableIcons = {
LogOut: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ExitToAppIcon {...props} ref={ref} />)
}
```

2) Usage

```
<MaterialTable
  title="User List"
  icons={tableIcons} 
actions{[{icon:tableIcons.LogOut,tooltip:'LogoutUser',onClick(event,rowData)=>{console.log('Logout clicked')}}]}
/>
```

In your case it will be `tableIcons.Print`